# RegEx in ASCII with hexa and octal

Tags: php, regex

Here's the problem:

```
if (preg_match_all("/[\x2F]/", $line, $match)) {
    print "Correct";
} else {
    print "error";
}
```

`x2F` in the ASCII table is `/`

When I run the code, it can't detect `/`, but when I insert other hexadecimal codes, for example `x2A`, it works. Just `/` and `\` don't works.

I also tried using octal form. it's still the same, just didn't work out with `/` and `\`.

Any solution to solve this?

The main idea of this is that, I am doing a web-based c++ compiler program, whenever student key in cin, then it will jump out a prompt box to let user to key in their value, but then if student type the code with `//cin`, my program still will jump the prompt box, I want it using RegEx to detect that if detected `//` then it wont run the specific line of the code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**While using double quotes use `\\` in your regex:**

```
preg_match_all("/[\\x2F]/", $line)
```

You don't even need character class:

```
preg_match_all("/\\x2F/", $line)
```

OR use single quotes:

```
preg_match_all('/\x2F/', $line)
```